# Python Searching for certain keywords in a string

Tags: python

Right now i have a list of each separate key word is there a way to make this into one array or string and search for individual words instead of having to separate each key word and make it repeatable?

```
keywordlist = ("pricing")
keywordlist1 = ("careers")
keywordlist2 = ("quotes")
keywordlist3 = ("telephone number")
keywordlist5 = ("about")
while True:
    question1 = raw_input("Is there anything I can help with today?   ")
    question_parts = question1.split(" ")
    for word in question_parts:
        if word.lower() in keywordlist:
            print("Yah i can show you some pricing:   ")
        elif word.lower() in keywordlist1:
            print("Here is our career page and feel free to apply:  ")
        elif word.lower() in keywordlist2:
            print("yah i can show you to our quote page: ")
        elif word.lower() in keywordlist3:
            print("Yah here is our contact page and feel free to contact us: ")
        elif word.lower() in keywordlist5:
            print("Here is some information about us:")
        goagain = raw_input("Would you like any More Help? (Yes/No)")
        if goagain == "Yes":
            #Get values again
            pass #or do whatever
        elif goagain != "Yes":
            print ("Bye!")
    break
```

Comment: Your `keywordlist` etc aren't lists or tuples, they're just strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
keywords = {"pricing": "Yah i can show you some pricing:   "
            "careers": "Here is our career page and feel free to apply:  "
            "quotes": "yah i can show you to our quote page: "
            "telephone": "Yah here is our contact page and feel free to contact us: "
            "about": "Here is some information about us:"}
while True:
    question1 = raw_input("Is there anything I can help with today?   ")
    question_parts = question1.lower().split()
    for word in question_parts:
        if word in keywords:
            print(keywords[word])
    goagain = raw_input("Would you like any More Help? (Yes/No)")
    if goagain == "Yes":
        #Get values again
    else:
        print ("Bye!")
        break
```

Comment: Nice work. FWIW, you could change that `.split` call to `question1.split()` to make it split on all whitespace.

Comment: @PM2Ring Done! And also convert to lowercase the whole input string in order to avoid converting it each time. Thank you!

Comment: Good idea. I forgot to mention that, although I did it in my own answer, (which I won't bother posting now that you've posted yours). Converting the case of a string is pretty cheap, but there's no point in doing it over & over on the same string.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions

```
import re 
KEYWORD_MAPPING = {
        "pricing": "Yah i can show you some pricing:",
        "careers": "Here is our career page and feel free to apply:",
        "quotes": "yah i can show you to our quote page:",
        "telephone": "Yah here is our contact page and feel free to contact us: ",
        "about": "Here is some information about us:"
}

def search_for_keyword(question):
    keyword_pattern = r'{}'.format('|'.join(KEYWORD_MAPPING.keys()))
    keyword = re.search(keyword_pattern, question, re.I).group()
    if not keyword:
         return False
    print(KEYWORD_MAPPING[keyword])
    return True

while True:
        question = input('enter a question')
        status = search_for_keyword(question)
        if not status:
             break
```